# The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=16.0.0". Got "14.18.3" (while deploying to vercel)

Tags: next.js, vercel

i was trying to deploy my next.js project to vercel but got the following error.

```
error datastore-pubsub@2.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=16.0.0". Got "14.18.3"
error Found incompatible module.
```

[image]

I tried deleting yarn.lock file but the same error showed up nonetheless.

Comment: go in package.json or yarn.lock remove "engines" :{
"node" : 14.x
}

Comment: no such line found in either of those files

Comment: here's the link to the github repo - https://github.com/xylanreeves/bitverse

Comment: ok let me see the GitHub link.

Comment: this is because the datastore-core package. it needs a higher version node see inside your vercel project setting you can specify the node version.

Comment: https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/node-js/node-js-version
see this link.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: It just shows 14.x and 12.x for now, so I think I have to overwrite it by defining it inside package.json file

Comment: yes, I checked node version 16 is not available in vercel try to specify it inside package.json.

Comment: It throws another error now:
Error: Found invalid Node.js Version: ">= 16.13.2". Please set "engines": { "node": "14.x" } in your `package.json` file to use Node.js

Comment: I suggest deploying your project to Heroku. because you can customize your node version.

Comment: Just create an account, create a project and connect the project to the GitHub repository.

Comment: I have two options now if I go with vercel, I can try using '--ignore-engines' with yarn or use 14.x version of node in my project.

Comment: I'll try heroku, but env (using env.local) works different in next.js though, that's what am worried about.

Comment: no, it is super easy to go just go setting tab => reval config vars

Comment: it is same as vercel

Comment: or if you want let me to deploy your project in my heroku first?

Comment: okay I'll give it a try! but vercel definitely needs to work on this 'node engine anomaly'

Comment: Nice job, you will definitely find a way for that if you solve it please comment your solution here.

Comment: did you try deploying it on your heroku?

Comment: No, I asked you but you didn't answer.

Comment: can you clone it and try ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242190/discussion-between-paiman-rasoli-and-xylan).

Answer (score 5):

Your dependency is relying on Node.js 16+, but Vercel currently does not have support, as we are dependent on AWS. You can follow along here: https://github.com/vercel/community/discussions/37

Should hopefully be resolved very soon.

Comment: so good to see you here, I follow you on youtube! And yes I read about the AWS thing, deployed the site on netlify for now. thank you and cheers  